# Toggle button visibility in for-loop

Tags: android, multithreading, button, visible, invisible

It must work, but is not working. When i start the app i see a button. Now i want that the button is visible and invisible.

```
for (k = 0; k < abc.length; ++k) {
try {

    if (k%2 != 0) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Thread.sleep(sleepMilliseconds);

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Or is the for loop so fast, that the android can't show it?
Nothing happens. I see the button.

I have a Thread.sleep(). Sleep Milliseconds is e.g. 100, 300 -> random. Also it can't be so fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a Thread.sleep(). Sleep Milliseconds is e.g. 100, 300 -> random. Also it can't be so fast.

You're sleeping *in the UI thread*. That's the problem. You're not letting the rest of the UI thread do its work.

If you want to periodically update the UI, you should be using a timer instead, or possibly call [`Handler.postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) at the end of each update, to schedule the next update. Alternatively, use the [Property Animation system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Answer (score 1):

WebnetMobile.com and Jon Skeet are right; you should be using a timer or animation for the effect you are seeking;

But if you really wanna do this in this your way then do as follows:

```
for (k = 0; k < abc.length; ++k) {
try {

    if (k%2 != 0) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread.sleep(sleepMilliseconds);

   } else {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     Thread.sleep(sleepMilliseconds);
    }


} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and make sire those milliseconds more than 500 to visually see them

Answer (score 1):

try this, hope help you..

declare a class variable and add this class and this method in your activity class

```
//variabe
boolean b;

//class
class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    @Override  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
      _yourActivity.this.updateUI();          
    }  

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {  
      this.removeMessages(0);  
      sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);  
    }

    public void stop(){
        super.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

}
```

and

```
//method
public void updateUI() {

 if (b) {
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    b=false;
 } else {
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    b=true;
 }
  mRedrawHandler.sleep(1000);
}
```

and then use this to start visibility invisibility of your button

```
mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler(); 
updateUI1();
```

and you can stop this using

```
mRedrawHandler.removeMessages(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to blink your button, apply animation on it with i.e. change of alpha channel.